# How can I save and load each bitmap after drawing, instead of re-drawing each stroke every time

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm working on a drawing application in Android/Java, and at the moment I re-draw every stroke instead of just loading the Bitmap. I'm thinking it will be a good idea to store a bitmap after each stroke and just load that onto the Canvas, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

This is what I have so far:

```
 protected void touchStart(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
 }

    protected void touchMove(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    protected void touchUp() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);

        mMyPathsDrawn.add(new Pair<>(mPath, mPaint));

        // Kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath = new Path();

        mPaint = new Paint(mPaint);
    }


    protected void onDraw() {
        if (mCanvas == null) {
            return;
        }
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(mBgBitmap, null, mSurfaceHolder.getSurfaceFrame(), null);
        for (Pair<Path, Paint> p : mPathsToDraw) {
            mCanvas.drawPath(p.first, p.second);
        }
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        Canvas surfaceCanvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        surfaceCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(surfaceCanvas);
    }
```

The workflow is: touchStart/touchMove/touchUp get called, and then onDraw gets called each time after each method.

If I am thinking correctly, I want to save mBitmap into an ArrayList / Stack, so everytime a new drawing happens, a new mBitmap is pushed into the array list / stack. Then, if someone wants to undo the last drawn stroke, I just need to pop the most recent Bitmap and load the 2nd most recent bitmap.

I'm trying to implement FloodFill to fill drawings after this, so I think switching to this approach will be better long-run.

Comment: See class Picture, nay be useful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.graphics.picture?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12

Comment: This seems interesting, so it records what has happened to that Canvas, and then when I want to display that new canvas I essentially do Picture.draw(mCanvas)?

Comment: Yes it is.........